# Transcendental complex numbers over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, transcendental-numbers

Possibly a dumb question, buy are there any transcendental complex numbers over reals? Seems like no.
I tried to google it, but it seems like, contrary to the material I've been educated upon in abstract algebra, the conventional definition for transcendental is having no polynomial over *rationals* to be zero of for a transcendental number.

Comment: Nevermind, I just rememberd that $\mathbb{C}$ is finite extension of the reals, so definitely no. I think the question is closed.

Comment: With the usual definition, any real number that is transcendental is also transcendental as a complex number. So what is *your* definition?

Comment: Well not mine exactly, but from the lectures i was attending, transcendental meant transcendental in a certain field extension, so in this case I was wondering about the extension $\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{R}$, i.e. about complex numbers with no polynomials with real coefficients for them. Which is pretty silly as it is finite extension and as a consequence algebraic, which I totally forgot.